# Typescript: use 'for' instead of many duplicated statements at compile-time?

Tags: typescript

There are two interfaces, one has some optional properties and other one does not:

```
interface ISTATE {
  events?: {
    [key in HookName]?: EventFunc
  },
  transitions?: {
    [transName: string]: TransFuncStr
  },
  store?: {
    [key: string]: any
  }
}

interface IVALIDSTATE {
  name: string
  events: {
    [key in HookName]?: EventFunc
  },
  transitions: {
    [transName: string]: TransFuncStr
  },
  store: {
    [key: string]: any
  }
}
```

I want to transform `ISTATE` to `IVALIDSTATE`. For each property in `ISTATE`, I have to check whether it exists, and copy value to `IVALIDSTATE` object:

```
function resolveStates(iStates: { [name: string]: ISTATE }): { [name: string]: IVALIDSTATE } {
  const ret: { [name: string]: IVALIDSTATE } = {}
  for (const i in iStates) {
    ret[i] = {} as IVALIDSTATE
    ret[i].name = i

    if (!iStates[i].events) {
      ret[i].events = {}
    } else {
      ret[i].events = iStates[i].events as any
    }

    if (!iStates[i].transitions) {
      // same if statement like'events'
    }

    if (!iStates[i].store) {
      // same if statement like'events'
    }
  }
  return ret
}
```

1. there are too many duplicated `if (!iStates[i].property) {}` statements, can I  use a `for ... in` statement instead of many duplicated statements? (for ... in requires runtime, so `keyof` could do this?)
2. is there any more simple way to transform optional property to non-optional? Now I have to use `as any` to avoid type checking.

Comment: For your second question, you could use `Partial<IVALIDSTATE>` instead of re-defining all properties in `ISTATE` (or `Required<ISTATE>` instead of `IVALIDSTATE`). It will make all propertiies (non-)optional. You can also use the `!` operator to remove the optionalness from a variable.

Comment: @N.Faure there is a property `name` which `ISTATE` does not have - although can use `&` join them... It's a good idea and I'll have a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, maybe you're looking for something like:

```
ret[i] = {} as IVALIDSTATE
ret[i].name = i
// new stuff below
const keys: (keyof ISTATE)[] = ['events','transitions','store'];        
keys.forEach(k => {
  const iStateK = iStates[i][k]; 
  ret[i][k] = iStateK || {};
});
```

Highlights:

- the `keys` array is declared as an array of type `keyof ISTATE`, so when we do `forEach()` on it, the compiler is happy with `ret[i][k]` and `iStates[i][k]`.
- the temporary variable `iStateK` is not necessary at runtime, but it helps the compiler do [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis). There's a [limitation in the compiler that prevents control flow anlaysis from happening when you check a property using bracket notation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530), as in `iStates[i][k]`.  The workaround is to assign the value of `iStates[i][k]` to a new variable, and do checking on that.
- Assigning `iStateK || {}` to `ret[i][k]` works because the compiler uses control flow analysis to realize that if `iStateK` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), the value will [short-circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) and the expression cannot be undefined; otherwise (if `iStateK` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)), the expression will be `{}` which is also not undefined.  So the compiler is satisfied that you are assigning a valid value to `ret[i][k]`.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!